# rendering inline view ionic not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an Ionic app, and initialised the project using the Ionic tabs template. This is working fine, however I am now trying to add a log in page, that will not be a tab.

I have tried to add this template a number of ways, but cannot get any to work. I have been trying to add the template inline in the html, but this is not working either, and is also not giving any errors.

The code I have is as follows:

**index.html**

```
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">

      <ion-view title="Home">
        <ion-content padding="true">
          <h2>Home Page</h2>
          <p>Heres the main route for the app.</p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>

    </script>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
 $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    }
  });
})

    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
      // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
      // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
      // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
      $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
      })


  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
  .state('tab', {
    url: "/tab",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

.state('tab.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'tab-login': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      }
    }
      })

      .state('tab.profile', {
        url: '/profile',
        views: {
          'tab-profile': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-profile.html',
            controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
            resolve: {
              postPromise: function(Posts) {
                return Posts.getAll();
              }
            }
          }
        }
      })
      .state('tab.post-detail', {
        url: '/profile/:postId',
        views: {
          'tab-profile': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/post-detail.html',
            controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('tab.settings', {
        url: '/settings',
        views: {
          'tab-settings': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-settings.html',
            controller: 'AccountCtrl'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('tab.camera', {
        url: '/camera',
        views: {
          'tab-camera': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-camera.html',
            controller: 'CameraCtrl'
          }
        }
      });
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/profile');
    });
```

For some bizarre reason this is not rendering the content on the html page. I have looked through each file in the project in case the issue was that it was initialized as a tab project, but could not find anything.

It seems as if there may be something very simple that I am missing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out why this was happening and how to fix this.

In the code above (boilerplate `tab-template` ionic code) in the index.html, there is a `<ion-nav-view>`.

The parent abstract state uses this nav view for it's rendering. If you want a view that is outside of the tabs, you just have to use that nav view.

The solution is to use another state that isn't a child state of the abstract one.

```
 .state('other', {
   url: "/other",
   templateUrl: "templates/other.html"
   controller: 'OtherCtrl'
 })
```

To get to this page you can link to this state from somewhere else in the app:

```
<a href="#/other">Go Somewhere Else</a>
```

Hopefully this helps someone else who comes across the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The first error that I see is that you did not define on your config the default routing :

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
```

Therefore, your app is starting but does not go to the default page.

If you are using `ionic serve` you can see that the uri stays `/`.
Try to manually go to `/home` and see if the page is rendered.

Comment: I actually did have that defined but didnt include as I thought I may have been adding too much code. See updated question reflecting complete  ```app.js``` file. I tried navigate to the route but to no avail